# Make Label visible in XAML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml

I have code for a Label in XAML:

```
>     <Label x:Name="check" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Height="23"
> FontSize="11" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

I am trying to show the label "check" in a condition(as below), but not getting any option.

```
 }
else
{
    check.??????????   
    check.Content = "Invalid!!!";
}
```

How to make the Lable "check" visible? Help please.

Comment: check.visibility=?? or what should be the code to make it visible, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

MSDN: [Visibility Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it would not be popping up in your IntelliSense should just be.

```
check.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```